# lxml in python 3: tags/elements that contain scripted elements and linefeed characters that tostring(method='html') can't figure out

Tags: python, html, encoding, lxml, liquid

EDIT:

So, after reviewing this further, it seems that it's an issue with how `tostring` is serializing.  All of the attributes themselves are fine if I fetch them via the `.attrib` dict, and in fact, the following code "serializes"/prints it as it should be:

```
for k in imgs[0].attrib.keys():
     print("{}=\"{}\"".format(k, imgs[0].attrib[k]))
```

outputs this:

```
src="{{ article.image | img_url: '100x' }}"
alt="{% if article.image.alt != blank %}{{ article.image.alt }}{% else %}{{ article.title | escape }}{% endif %}"
data-src="{{ article.image | img_url: '1400x', format: 'pjpg' }}"
class="lazyload {{ settings.image_loading_style }}"
sizes="100vw"
srcset="{{ article.image | img_url: '480x', format: 'pjpg' }} 480w,
                  {{ article.image | img_url: '765x', format: 'pjpg' }} 765w,
                  {{ article.image | img_url: '1400x', format: 'pjpg' }} 1400w,
                  {{ article.image | img_url: '2048x', format: 'pjpg' }} 2048w"
```

Is there any way to force tostring to serialize specific string encoding?  Somehow it's turning \n characters in to linefeed escape characters that aren't being interpreted properly.  Yes-- I know-- linefeeds in attrbitues aren't ideal, but they're also not illegal-- and can help readability.

ORIGINAL QUESTION:

I'm using the `lxml` library (python 3.7) to parse and modify some html code, with the intent of writing it back as unscathed as possible.  Mainly it's updating attributes, but it's working inside .  It works fantastic except in a few cases, and I can't figure out how best to solve it.  I should mention that these are html files mixed with the Liquid templating syntax, so I'm guessing that is the source of some of the confusion.

The python3 code looks like this:

```
parser = etree.HTMLParser()
tree = etree.parse(fname, parser)
imgs = tree.xpath('.//img')

print(etree.tostring(imgs[0], encoding='unicode', method='html')
```

Consider the following img element from within an html file (this uses scripted elements within some of the attributes that contain curly braces):

```
<img  src="{{ a.image | img_url: '100x' }}"
      alt="{% if a.image.alt != blank %}{{ a.image.alt }}{% else %}{{ a.title | escape }}{% endif %}"
      data-src="{{ article.image | img_url: '1400x', format: 'pjpg' }}"
      class="lazyload {{ settings.image_loading_style }}"
      sizes="100vw"
      srcset="{{ a.image | img_url: '480x', format: 'pjpg' }} 480w,
              {{ a.image | img_url: '765x', format: 'pjpg' }} 765w,
              {{ a.image | img_url: '1400x', format: 'pjpg' }} 1400w,
              {{ a.image | img_url: '2048x', format: 'pjpg' }} 2048w"
       />
```

lxml parses this fine, but he problem is (as you can see below) is when I use `etree.tostring()` to print the element back out, not only does it not retain the linefeeds from the original version, where all the attributes are on seperate lines (which is annoying but not a huge deal) it also adds

```
&#10;
```

at the end of every one of the lines within `srcset`, so when I try to print the elemtn with etree.tostring(), I get this (sorry you'll have to scroll all the way to the right where you can see all the `&#10`:

```
<img src="{{ a.image | img_url: '100x' }}" alt="{% if a.image.alt != blank %}{{ article.image.alt }}{% else %}{{ a.title | escape }}{% endif %}" data-src="{{ a.image | img_url: '1400x', format: 'pjpg' }}" class="lazyload {{ settings.image_loading_style }}" sizes="100vw" data-srcset="{{ a.image | img_url: '480x', format: 'pjpg' }} 480w,&#10;                  {{ a.image | img_url: '765x', format: 'pjpg' }} 765w,&#10;                  {{ a.image | img_url: '1400x', format: 'pjpg' }} 1400w,&#10;                  {{ a.image | img_url: '2048x', format: 'pjpg' }} 2048w"/>
```

Now... if I supply the method='html' to the etree.tostring() method, it properly handles the linefeeds (&#10) but then completely messes up the curly braces inside the src/alt attributes, as you can see here:

```
<img src="%7B%7B%20a.image%20%7C%20img_url:%20'100x'%20%7D%7D" alt="{% if a.image.alt != blank %}{{ a.image.alt }}{% else %}{{ a.title | escape }}{% endif %}" data-src="{{ a.image | img_url: '1200x', format: 'pjpg' }}" class="lazyload {{ settings.image_loading_style }}" sizes="auto" srcset="{{ a.image | img_url: '480x', format: 'pjpg' }} 480w,
                                {{ a.image | img_url: '600x', format: 'pjpg' }} 600w,
                                {{ a.image | img_url: '800x', format: 'pjpg' }} 800w,
                                {{ a.image | img_url: '1200x', format: 'pjpg' }} 1200w">
```

Been stuck on this a couple hours now.  I don't normally use lxml for anything other than web scraping, and this is my first time trying to parse and modify/write html so maybe I'm missing something.  I'm using `encoding='unicode'` with all the etree.tostring() methods.

At this point it might be easier for me just to use sed or re and modify the tags in the file in-place, but I was hoping to be able to do this logically inside Python.  I already tried BeautifulSoup but that destroys the formatting of the original file and doesn't have control over attribute order, which while functionally isn't wrong, makes it harder to read and keep consistent.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: please share your expected output !

Comment: It should be exactly like the original formatting-- or at least, functionally correct.  But method='html' output doesn't like "{{ apparently, and turns it into  %7B%7B%20

Comment: There is no problem with `&#10;` in the attribute value. It's a linefeed character, HTML encoded. lxml is doing the right thing. It might not be what you expect, but the output is *technically* 100% correct.

Comment: However, if you want to get *literal* linefeed characters, replace `'&#10;'` with `'\n'` after the lxml `.tostring()` call.

Comment: Yeah-- I was hoping there was an easier solution in the serialization.  I want the parser to retain as much of the previous formatting as possible, but I'm starting to learn that's not really the parser's concern, and that this will probably be a job for both a parser and a traditional regex sub.  Thank you!

Comment: Well. There is nothing stopping you from overriding ("monkey-patching") internal functions in Python's classes. You can remove the code that replaces `\n` with `&#10;`. Personally I find search-and-replace after the fact the more elegant option: less code, less complexity, less that can go wrong, less to explain. Normally I am strictly against against carrying out string operations on HTML, but in this specific case nothing can break.